# Recovering Windows Partition After Deleting It

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

So after installing Ubuntu, I wanted to get rid of Windows. So I installed GParted and then looked through it. I deleted just 1 Partition and restarted my System.

Now ever since I installed Ubuntu(Which is today), everytime I booted-up my PC, it would automatically go onto Windows and then I'd have to boot-up Ubuntu from there. And since I've deleted 1 Partition, I cannot get back into Windows. All it shows is the Troubleshooting-Panel and what OS I want to boot-up(Luckily enough, I can still boot-up Ubuntu).

I really want to recover this Windows Partition. I'm really scared in case I can't get Windows back or I've broken a really important part of my PC.

Comment: This might help https://ubuverse.com/recover-a-disk-partition-with-testdisk-and-gparted-live/

Comment: fyi:  I've used a utility available for purchase online a couple of times restoring NTFS files after format.  The software (can't find it's name) scanned the drive and restored files (to another drive).  It took about 3 days for a 160gb partition to run, and most files were FILE0AF4  (ie. filename lost; content of files were recovered but not always name) though some directories were complete but put in a directory named DIR00013. This cheap tool was worth it because I got back the church data they lost, but it was labor-intensive re-creating directories/filenames structure afterwards.